# Convert hex encoded string to byte array

Tags: converting, r, vectors

The following should read a hex string such as `"ece998a2fb"` into vector `236 233 152 162 251`. I was unable to find any built in method for doing this.

```r
as.byte.vector <- function(hex.string) {
  vapply(seq(to=nchar(hex.string), by=2), function(idx) {
    as.numeric(paste("0x", substr(hex.string, idx, idx+1), sep=''))
  }, FUN.VALUE = double(1))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One improvement is you can use the vectorized function `substring` rather than `substr`. This way, you can precompute all hexadecimal pairs and feed them directly into `paste` and `as.numeric` which are also vectorized. This removes the need for `vapply` (a disguised and slowish `for` loop).

You could also use `paste0` as a shortcut for `paste(, sep = "")`. `paste0` has been around for what seems like a couple years. If you are concerned about compatibility with older versions of R, then yes, it is safer to stick with `paste`.

I could be wrong but I see no reason not to output a vector of integers instead of numerics. That integers use less memory and are not subject to floating point errors are two strong reasons to prefer them over numerics.

It is also a good idea to add input checks to test your assumptions. Here it seems that the input must be a character vector of length 1.

This comment is more subjective. You have crammed a lot of operations into a single statement. I can count 8 functions including the anonymous one you created. That really makes your code hard to understand.

In all, I would have written the function like this:

```
as.byte.vector <- function(hex.string) {
   stopifnot(is.character(hex.string), length(hex.string) == 1L)
   start.idx <- seq(from = 1L, to = nchar(hex.string), by = 2L)
   end.idx <- start.idx + 1L
   hex.pairs <- substring(hex.string, start.idx, end.idx)
   prefixed.pairs <- paste0("0x", hex.pairs)
   as.integer(prefixed.pairs)
}
```

I hope you will agree that it is easier to read when the code is broken out this way, with each statement using a very few functions, and where the names of the variables holding intermediate results help understand the process.

This should already be faster than your version, thanks to the replacement of `vapply`. If speed is a real concern, you could make significant improvement by replacing `substring` with the following regular expression trick:

```
hex.pairs <- strsplit(gsub("(..)", "\\1 ", hex.string), " ")[[1]]
```

(We insert a space every two characters, then split on white space.)

Comment: I'm very new to R and appreciate the feedback. So far the only style/code guidelines I've been given are to indent code. Creating the corresponding `end.idx` sequence and vectorizing the `substring` call seem obvious, now that I've seen it, but things I hadn't happened upon yet. Thanks! I am quite curious: How would the string manipulation be faster than using `substring`?

Comment: You would have to look at how the functions are implemented to tell for sure, but my guess is that every time you call `substring`, it is scanning the whole string from the left. Whereas `gsub` and `strsplit` only scan it once.

Comment: @flodel, just checked: `gsub` + `strsplit` is slower than `substring`. (Possibly because the additional spaces imply copying?)

Comment: More likely because of overheads, as you tested with extremely small inputs. You should see that `gsub + strsplit` is a lot faster as you increase the input size.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @flodel's nice answer, `hex.pairs` can directly be converted:

```
strtoi (hex.pairs, base = 16L)
```

Not prefixing with `0x` will shave off another 10% or so of the runtime.

The `gsub` / `strsplit` combination is somewhat slower (according to `microbenchmark` of the provided string:

```
Unit: microseconds
      expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq     max neval  cld
    prefix 44.628 46.445 49.27500 48.4000 49.1685  88.628   100  b  
    strtoi 39.181 41.905 45.15926 43.5110 45.2570  97.149   100 a   
gsubstrtoi 47.772 51.159 55.23254 52.5910 54.7905 138.565   100   c 
      orig 74.870 76.790 84.32210 79.9685 90.3745 171.809   100    d
```

`prefix` is @flodel's version, `strtoi` skips the prefixing and directly uses `strtoi`, `gsubstrtoi` splits by `gsub` + `strsplit`; `orig` is the OP's version.

Comment: +1 for the solution but I cringe a little at the speed tests and the hasty conclusions. Speed tests are meaningful when you specify the size of the inputs and test with various input sizes. Here, I imagine that you tested with the OP's example which is extremely small. With such sizes, we could argue that 5~40 microseconds are not going to make a big difference. And the differences will likely come from meaningless overheads the various approaches include (e.g. input checking, handling of NAs, etc.)

Comment: I suggested `gsub + strsplit` as an alternative to `substring` if "speed is a real concern". In my mind, that's if the user plan to use much larger input strings, the only situation where differences will create meaningful differences. I'd encourage you to add a test with `hex.string <- paste(sample(c(0:9, LETTERS[1:6]), N, TRUE), collapse = "")` for much larger values of `N` if you have the time. `gsubstrtoi` is a clear/visible winner with `N=1e4` and frankly the only one that will scale nicely if you go over.

Comment: @flodel: fair enough - I tested (and had in mind) lots of calls with small inputs (played only with N up to around 50). More speedup may anyways be gained by thinking about where the strings come from and whether they could be processed in a way that chops them immediately into 2 char groups. (or move to Rcpp)